# Do inline styles get autoprefixed?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autoprefixer

I'm creating an app with react and material UI. Autoprefixer is in the `package.json` and configured in webpack like so:

```
 postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          '>1%',
          'last 4 versions',
          'Firefox ESR',
          'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        ]
      }),
    ];
},
```

it also says this:

```
// "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
// "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
// "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
// In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
// in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
},
```

I'm using inline styles (I know), are they auto prefixed?

Can I configure them to be? Using radium for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can use [postcss-js](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-js) for this. It's thankfully mentioned in the `autoprefixer` docs:

https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#css-in-js

Comment: [CSS-in-JS Future](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/css-in-javascript-the-future-of-component-based-styling-70b161a79a32?gi=83c0c992bf3c) is blog that tells why css-in-js is becoming so popular.

There are many libraries out there supporting this structure - `aphrodite`, `jss`, `radium` .. so on...